# Making DataModel from non empty json gives null

Tags: dart

There is a model

```
class DataModel {
  String name;
  String img;
  int price;
  int people;
  int stars;
  String description;
  String location;

  DataModel({
    required this.name,
    required this.img,
    required this.price,
    required this.people,
    required this.stars,
    required this.description,
    required this.location,
  });

  factory DataModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return DataModel(
      name: json['name'],
      img: json['img'],
      price: json['price'],
      people: json['people'],
      stars: json['stars'],
      description: json['description,'],
      location: json['location'],
    );
  }
}
```

and a function where I get null

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter_cubit/services/data_model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class DataServices {
  String baseUrl = 'http://******';

  Future<List<DataModel>> getInfo() async {
    String apiUrl = '/****';
    http.Response res = await http.get(Uri.parse(baseUrl + apiUrl));
    try {
      print('response status:${res.statusCode}');

      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        print('----------1');
        List<dynamic> list = json.decode(res.body);
        print(list[0]); // only first imem just for example the data isn't empty
        print('----------2');

        // the error is on the next line
        List<DataModel> result = list.map((e) => DataModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
 
        print('----------3');
        print(result);
        return result;
      } else {
        return <DataModel>[];
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return <DataModel>[];
    }
  }
}
```

The output from the above function

```
I/flutter ( 6979): response status:200
I/flutter ( 6979): ----------1
I/flutter ( 6979): {id: 1, name: British Columbia, description: This 134 kilometers Highway 99 trail gives you a taste of the Canada mountains, from Horseshoe Bay in the north of Vancouver to Pemberton. , price: 1276, stars: 4, people: 5, selected_people: 5, img: images/f9d4b5e088c7bc70b7bbd51cd89e71b6.jpeg, location: Canada, British Columbia, created_at: 2021-11-17T10:09:08.000000Z, updated_at: 2021-11-19T13:39:55.000000Z}
I/flutter ( 6979): ----------2
I/flutter ( 6979): type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

Why do I get null on error-line of the code?

the original json from api

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"British Columbia",
      "description":"This 134 kilometers Highway 99 trail gives you a taste of the Canada mountains, from Horseshoe Bay in the north of Vancouver to Pemberton. ",
      "price":1276,
      "stars":4,
      "people":5,
      "selected_people":5,
      "img":"images\/f9d4b5e088c7bc70b7bbd51cd89e71b6.jpeg",
      "location":"Canada, British Columbia",
      "created_at":"2021-11-17T10:09:08.000000Z",
      "updated_at":"2021-11-19T13:39:55.000000Z"
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"Icefields",
      "description":"This stretches for a straight 234 kilometers from Banff to Jasper. The Icefields Parkway offers you the picturesque panorama of Alberta\u2019s most talked about mountain vistas. ",
      "price":2153,
      "stars":5,
      "people":5,
      "selected_people":3,
      "img":"images\/1a2d25d3c5ea7912982e37b8005bbebe.jpeg",
      "location":"Icefields, Alberta",
      "created_at":"2021-11-17T10:10:43.000000Z",
      "updated_at":"2021-11-19T14:18:09.000000Z"
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "name":"Moraine Lake",
      "description":"Moraine Lake is yet another astonishing geographical location that you cannot afford to miss out on if you\u2019re traveling along the Icefields Parkway. ",
      "price":3456,
      "stars":3,
      "people":5,
      "selected_people":4,
      "img":"images\/9a4079ae9e67ca51b9fdf4670a5795f4.jpeg",
      "location":"Moraine Lake, Alberta",
      "created_at":"2021-11-17T10:16:31.000000Z",
      "updated_at":"2021-11-19T13:40:36.000000Z"
   },
   {
      "id":4,
      "name":"Ontario",
      "description":"If you\u2019re in Canada and if you\u2019re a sucker for mountains, Killarney Provincial Park in Ontario is your best catch for Canada mountains near Toronto. ",
      "price":3312,
      "stars":4,
      "people":5,
      "selected_people":3,
      "img":"images\/24fe838b325456a0ca7fc2249409de3f.jpeg",
      "location":"Killarney Provincial Park",
      "created_at":"2021-11-17T10:18:46.000000Z",
      "updated_at":"2021-11-19T13:40:44.000000Z"
   },
   {
      "id":5,
      "name":"Gaza",
      "description":"Dome of the rock the beautiful and amazing human made architectural.",
      "price":10,
      "stars":5,
      "people":5,
      "selected_people":4,
      "img":"images\/9aaf2377eb3e0978ecb0e17717579a2b.jpg",
      "location":"Palestine, Gaza",
      "created_at":"2021-12-08T12:29:53.000000Z",
      "updated_at":"2021-12-08T12:29:53.000000Z"
   }
]
```

Comment: How does your JSON look? Does it have all the fields described in `DataModel`? Remember, you are looping though all elements in the JSON list and not just the first element. So one of the elements might miss one of the properties or the property is the to `null`.

Comment: Also, I would expect you to get a stacktrace after that error message which points out the line where the error comes from (so you can see what field is missing or have the `null` value).

Comment: @julemand101 json added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in your factory Constructor

```
  factory DataModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return DataModel(
      name: json['name'],
      img: json['img'],
      price: json['price'],
      people: json['people'],
      stars: json['stars'],
      description: json['description,'], //Here; You added a comma.
      location: json['location'],
    );
  }
```

Use this:

```
  factory DataModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return DataModel(
      name: json['name'],
      img: json['img'],
      price: json['price'],
      people: json['people'],
      stars: json['stars'],
      description: json['description'], //Comma removed.
      location: json['location'],
    );
  }
```